# Different definitions of derivation at a point

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, tangent-bundle, germs

I have come across the following two different definitions for "derivation at a point" (for both definitions, assume M is a smooth manifold and $p \in M$):

> Def 1: A derivation at p is an $\mathbb{R}$-linear map $\delta : C^{\infty}(M) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying the Leibniz identity $\delta(fg) = \delta(f) g(p) + f(p) \delta(g)$
>
> Def 2: A derivation at p is an $\mathbb{R}$-linear map $\delta : C_p^{\infty}(M) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying the Leibniz identity $\delta(fg) = \delta(f) g(p) + f(p) \delta(g)$

Both are claimed to define the same notion of the tangent space $T_pM$, even though one is defined as maps from the algebra of functions and the other from the algebra of germs of functions.

**Question:**  How can I construct an isomorphism between the vector space of derivations according to definition 1 and the vector space of derivations according to definition 2?

My idea has been to construct a map which takes functions to their germs as a quotient map; however, I can't figure out how to show that germ(g) = germ(f) $\implies \delta(g) = \delta(f)$ for all definition 1 derivations.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: For a neighborhood of $p$ construct a smooth function $h$ that is zero outside of that neighborhood and $h(p)=1$ on a compact neighborhood contained in the first. If $f,g$ are equal as germs. Take $h$ corresponding to the neighborhood in which $f$ and $g$ are equal. Then $0=\delta((f-g)h)=\delta((f-g))+(f-g)(p)\delta(h)=\delta(f-g)$. This shows that $\delta$ depends only on the germ: $\delta(f-g)=0$ or $\delta(f)=\delta(g)$. The first equality is because $(f-g)h\equiv 0$, the second is Leibniz's, and the last is because $(f-g)(p)=0$.

Comment: @orole - that should have been an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @PaulSinclair If you think so, then do it. Write it down there.